dotenv is not seeing .env files
dotenv path will not pick up .env files but sees everything else in the folder.
i have tried

dotenv.config({path:'relative path'})
dotenv.config({path:'absolute path'})

when i try the relative path it sees everything except .env file. like it dosen't exist. i open it up in vs code / file explorer, it is very much there.
the structure is like this:
root:
modules
playwright-report
pupputeer
test-results
tests
.env
example.spec.ts
login.test.ts
tests-examples
.gitignore
package-lock.json
package.json
playwright.config.ts

login.test.ts code
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: './tests/.env' });
import { firefox, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("Login test demo", async () => {
const browser = await firefox.launch();
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();

      console.log(process.env);
    
      await page.goto("https://ecommerce-playground.lambdatest.io/");
      await page.hover("//a[@data-toggle='dropdown']//span[contains(.,'My account')]");
      await page.click("text=Login");
    
      // await page.fill("input[name='email']", );

});

playwright.config.ts code

   import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";

   const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
      use: {
         headless: false
      },
      
      testMatch: ["tests/login.test.ts"]
   }

   export default config;

package.json code:
{
   "type": "commonjs",
   "name": "scrape",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node tests-examples/demo-todo-app.spec.ts"
   },
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "description": "",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@playwright/test": "^1.46.1",
      "@types/node": "^22.5.0"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
      "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
   }
}


i run npx playwright test, to launch

owner/permissions?

What environment variable are you expecting to be present? Can you give an example of the .env file contents?

Is there a reason you are importing and trying to consume .env directly in the test rather than in playwright.config.ts?  The way you are currently trying to do it will require the same code in each test.....

.env file : EMAIL:moregiberish@gmail.com
PASS:giberish

please don´t use XPath or css. PW offers handy locators. e.g. page.getByText('My account') and then .selectOption(...) or page.getByRole('button', {name: Login}). Pw´s locators are strict which xpath and css don´t. Why is your playwright.config.ts is different to example? Have you tried moving .env to top level and include require('dotenv').config(); in playwright.config.ts ? I have access to .env everywhere in my project by doing this.

@Ryan please [edit] your question to provide details like that. At a quick glance though, your .env format is simply incorrect. Each line should look like EMAIL=moregiberish@gmail.com and PASS=giberish. See https://www.dotenv.org/docs/security/env

To ensure the .env file is correctly formatted, double-check that the two lines defining GITHUB_TOKEN and GITHUB_USERNAME don't have semicolons at the end. The correct format should look like this:
GITHUB_TOKEN=your_token_here
GITHUB_USERNAME=your_username_here

This small adjustment can make a big difference in how the environment variables are read and used by the application. It's a common oversight that can lead to unexpected behavior, so it's always worth verifying.
